# Memory usage of jq's --slurp option

Tags: jq

Does the `--slurp` option load the entire input in memory before processing it or has it been optimized somehow in order to avoid that?

Comment: It might be smart enough to know that if you have a trivial filter (`'.'`), it will know that it won't need to. But in general, I wouldn't expect it to. Even if it could, how would you expect it to in general?

Comment: For example, filters like `add` and `length` could work without the need for the entire file to reside in memory at once. I use jq a lot with filters like those. I could `--stream` the input, although it's a bit more cumbersome. I don't have a general expectation, I'm more interested in practical details.

Comment: Jeff - With --slurp, even "." requires a complete parse of all the input (e.g. jq has to check the input is all valid before it can begin to emit anything).  The main alternative to --slurp is "map/reduce"; for example, jq could be invoked separately for the map and reduce operations.

Comment: @peak: One could conceive that while it does have to parse, it wouldn't necessarily have to keep it in memory and just output immediately.

Comment: @memeplex: I would hope that if the filter ends with an aggregate, it would recognize such a case. It does some [TCO](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Advanced-Topics) but that's the only optimization that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to the question is essentially "yes": commands such as "jq --slurp . FILE ...." store the parsed input as an array in memory.   This will often require more memory than the size of the input itself -- consider for example that JSON objects are stored as hash tables.

With jq 1.5 there are often better alternatives than "slurping" the input. Most notably, perhaps, the `inputs` filter works very nicely with `reduce` and `foreach`.  (If you do use `inputs` then don't forget you will probably want to invoke jq with the "-n" option.)