# JQ: Cannot index string with string "result"

Tags: jq

So I have many files that follow this structure. Each contains over 500 lines.

file1.json:

```json
{"result": {"lead": [{"id": "1234", "accountID": null, "ownerID": "5678", "companyName": "Hello", "title": "Manager", "firstName": "Nick", "lastName": "Name", "street": null, "city": "Somewhere", "country": "Canada", "state": null, "zipcode": null, "emailAddress": "someone@somewhere.com", "website": "somewhere.com", "phoneNumber": "", "officePhoneNumber": null, "phoneNumberExtension": null, "mobilePhoneNumber": "", "faxNumber": null, "description": "Website", "campaignID": "12345678", "trackingID": null, "industry": null, "active": "1", "isQualified": "1", "isContact": "1", "isCustomer": "0", "status": "3", "updateTimestamp": "2020-11-06 09:44:04", "createTimestamp": "2018-07-17 15:59:42", "leadScoreWeighted": "6", "leadScore": "15", "isUnsubscribed": "1", "leadStatus": "contactWithOpp", "persona": ""}]}}
```

file2.json

```json
{"result": {"lead": [{"id": "2234", "accountID": null, "ownerID": "5678", "companyName": "Hello", "title": "Manager", "firstName": "Martin", "lastName": "Name", "street": null, "city": "Somewhere", "country": "Canada", "state": null, "zipcode": null, "emailAddress": "someone@somewhere.com", "website": "somewhere.com", "phoneNumber": "", "officePhoneNumber": null, "phoneNumberExtension": null, "mobilePhoneNumber": "", "faxNumber": null, "description": "Website", "campaignID": "12345678", "trackingID": null, "industry": null, "active": "1", "isQualified": "1", "isContact": "1", "isCustomer": "0", "status": "3", "updateTimestamp": "2020-11-06 09:44:04", "createTimestamp": "2018-07-17 15:59:42", "leadScoreWeighted": "6", "leadScore": "15", "isUnsubscribed": "1", "leadStatus": "contactWithOpp", "persona": ""}]}}
```

Initial JQ:

```
.result.lead[].id
```

They start:

```
{
  "result": {
    "lead": [
      {
        "id": "1234",
```

Each contains an un-named object, containing the result object, containing an array named lead, containing objects.

I want to combine and process together the multiple files into one. I can consume  various structures (e.g. a different json) or formats (e.g. CSV) as the output, but ideally I'd end up with a one output file.

JQ and JQPlay says:

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:0): Cannot index string with string "result"
exit status 5
```

I'm sure my error is simple but I can't see it!

Thanks

Edit:

```
jq -f do-001-flatten-leads.jq  leads1.json
```

This works.

But to process together everything (assuming I'm supposed to slurp):

```
jq -f do-001-flatten-leads.jq -s leads1.json leads2.json
```

Shows the error messsage "Cannot index string with string "result"

EDIT: In my prior example (https://jqplay.org/s/Y_UclBq1xa), I wrongly selected "raw" in JQ. I want to select "slurpfiles" but that is not an option.

In https://jqplay.org/s/X5XAfDsuV7 I have added two entries assuming that behaves consistently with slurpfiles.

From [Memory usage of jq's --slurp option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34778425/memory-usage-of-jqs-slurp-option) I'm coming to believe that I ought to avoid slurping, in favour of using multiple inputs. I'm not doing anything that summarizes, only really selecting columns and maybe format so some sort of streaming seems preferable.

Comment: Why do you have raw input checked in the jq play snippet? ( unchecking it should fix your problem)

Comment: You're not saying what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks all. I've updated the question for clarity. Apologies for the gaps in my description.

Answer (score 0):

[image: jqplay website]

Uncheck "Raw Input" and you get a proper output.

Comment: Thanks.  I've updated the question for clarity. Apologies for the gaps in my description

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not seem to have specified how you want to combine the files, it’s difficult to do more than offer the following guidance:

1. As you guessed, do not use the -s option
2. Use `inputs` and the -n command-line option, e.g. as follows:

```
reduce inputs as $in (null; . + $in.result.lead)
```

Comment: Thanks - I'm reading https://blog.differentpla.net/blog/2019/01/11/jq-reduce/ and will comment again shortly.